# How to access VTK's class enumeration field

Tags: c++, vtk

I'm having problems trying to acces a enumeration field in my following code.

```
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkGenericDataObjectReader> reader =
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkGenericDataObjectReader>::New();
    reader->SetFileName(file_name);
    reader->Update();

    vtkSmartPointer<vtkDataObject> vtk_data = reader->GetOutput();


    vtkSmartPointer<vtkFieldData> points = 
        vtk_data->GetAttributesAsFieldData(vtkDataObject::AttributeTypes.POINT);
    //points->PrintSelf(cout, 0);
```

However I get the following error:

> error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
>                vtk_data->GetAttributesAsFieldData(int(vtkDataObject::AttributeTypes.POINT));

Comment: What is an *enumeration field*? Is it simply a `vtkPointData` or `vtkCellData` scalar or vector array?

Comment: [Here](https://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkDataObject.html#a5a7947e4aa8e4668cf870f4a592e3625) both methods need a type as a parameter. One of [these](https://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkDataObject.html#a75b13d501194938772601cb0a3385f20) however I cant seem to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me ( using GCC 8.1 ) the following compiles without any error.

```
#include <vtkDataObject.h>

int main(){
    auto a = vtkDataObject::AttributeTypes::POINT;    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Adding "set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)" to CMakeLists.txt solved the problem.